# Define CI/CD for Cassandara Database Objects?

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I mean what is the best way to manage Schema changes when we move from lower environment to higher environments

Answer (score 0):

You can alter column families but there's a big restriction: You can only add columns. 
If you want to switch to a whole new schema, it's only one solution available:

1. Make a full backup (You can use snapshots or you have to select your data)
2. Create a new cluster
3. Create the new schema on this new cluster
4. Create a migration script

Comment: I mean adding new column families/columns to the existing ones not switching to the whole new schema. Instead of manually doing that, I wanted to know if there is any best practice for managing schema changes